# Sorting all matrix fields from multiple entries as one list

Tags: matrix, datetime, sorting, sort

I have a section with a matrix field that collects multiple notes for each entry, each marked by the date the note is entered. Conceptually, the data is organized within the entries as:

```
Entry A
     Jan 1     Note
     Mar 1     Note

Entry B
     Feb 1     Note
     Apr 1     Note
```

I would like to extract all the notes from all the entries, and then display the collected information sorted by the dates the notes were entered, as in:

```
Jan 1    Note     Entry A
Feb 1    Note     Entry B
Mar 1    Note     Entry A
Apr 1    Note     Entry B
```

Is this possible in Craft? I'm aware of the SuperSorter plugin, but am not sure whether what I am explaining is possible. If it is, I'm unclear about the syntax required to construct the query properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with [matrix block queries](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/matrix-blocks.html#querying-matrix-blocks). Instead of going through entries to get the matrix blocks, you can query matrix blocks independently with a custom sort order.

```twig
{% set notesByDate = craft.matrixBlocks()
    .type('note')
    .orderBy('note_date ASC')
    .all()
%}
```

Replace `note` with the handle of the matrix block type of your notes and `note_date` with the handle of the date field.

This will give you a list of matrix blocks. From the matrix blocks, you can get the owner entry using [MatrixBlock::getOwner()](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v4/craft-elements-matrixblock.html#method-getowner):

```twig
{% for note in notesByDate %}
    Date: {{ note.date | date('medium') }}
    Note: {{ note.note }}
    Entry: {{ note.getOwner().title }}
{% endfor %}
```

### Limiting matrix blocks to specific section

You can't limit a matrix block query to a specific section directly since they don't belong to a section. Matrix blocks are owned by entries and those entries belong to a section. So you need to limit the matrix query to matrix blocks that are [owned by](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/matrix-blocks.html#ownerid) the entries in that section:

```twig
{% set entriesInSection = craft.entries().section('myCustomSection').ids() %}
{% set notesByDateInCustomSection = craft.matrixBlocks()
    .type('note')
    .orderBy('note_date ASC')
    .ownerId(entriesInSection)
    .all()
%}
```

Comment: Brilliant - just what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: While this got me 99% of the way there, I use this particular matrix block in several sections of the site. I want to filter the output to results from a particular section. I found that Matrix Blocks to not accept a .section() parameter. Any way to filter these matrixBlock results by section?

Comment: @EdHebert I've added an example for limiting the query to a specific section!

Comment: thanks so much - worked!